# Difference between <p id=""> and <div id=""><p>

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between applying id's or classes to the element and enclosing the element into div's with classes or id's?

I.e., the difference between, let's say,
`<p id="BLAH">Testing</p>` and `<div id="BLAH"><p>Testing</p>`.

It would be good to have some examples.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place for people to write you tutorials on introductory topics. Head over to MDN and start reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: ids should be unique, classes are not unique https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: It all really depends on what you're trying to do. I would be as specific as possible with the IDs if you plan on selecting them with jQuery to avoid a lot of extra DOM traversal. I guess I'd have the same answer if you're applying CSS, like text styling to a specific P tag. I would use an ID on a div if I were creating a container for placement, or applying CSS to elements on a div-by-div basis (e.g. creating cards, each with different text styling).

Comment: Posted 6 years in, there are probably multiple duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are no formal difference on the effect (both are block elements) applied by `ID` or `CLASS`. But: `div` is better referred for a block of content having different nested elements (all type of content), `p` which is used for paragraphs (text). So the semantics of objects is different.